# Moving a router's input port with DD-WRT

Tags: router

I have a Linksys router with DD-WRT on it. The ethernet ports on the back are Internet and Local 1; 2; 3; and 4. Only locals 2, 3, and 4 respond to ping, and I need the Internet one to get OpenVPN working (I think - different issue. It says it's running, but it's not accepting connections).

Anyway, I was wondering if I could make another, say Local 4, be the Internet port. Is there something in the control panel, or am I better off just waiting for the new one to arrive?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I think it might be possible through the VLAN assignments with DD-WRT.

Comment: I thought as much. Not sure what to do with that, though.

Comment: It looks the like WAN/Internet port is assigned to VLAN1 by default, you should be able to add one of the other four ports by also assigning it to the same VLAN. If it works, it looks like you have to give up a LAN port. You should check with the DD-WRT folks for a definitive answer.